StepDefinition not linking to feature file in IntelliJ
My Step definition isn't linking to my feature file, and I get the below error although I have already created a step definition:
"Step undefined
You can implement this step and 6 other step(s) using the snippet(s) below:"
Below is my POM file:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>21</source>
                <target>21</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Please suggest ways in which I can overcome this issue. I have already tried gluing my Step definition package. The error still persists.

What does the rest of your project look like? How are you running Cucumber?

Please provide a minimal sample project so I can reproduce the issue without including your sensitive code on GitHub. Thank you! Also, please try the latest IDEA 2024.2.1 might be helpful.

Can you share a screenshot of the issue? It sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-347976.
